# HDD SMART seek error rate fail but is back to 0

Tags: hard-drive

I am setting up my very first raid, utilizing an old computer as a fileserver for backups seemed like a good idea. So I bought 4 new Toshiba Nas drives. 1 was DOA, beeping (no buzz, proper beep) and sctratching. Warranty tooks weeks but now I got a new drive and I got to it.

Ubuntu 20.04 up to date
mdadm

I finished the configuration yesterday and mdadm started to work, rebuilding. I suppose it needs to get those parity bits saying the disks are empty.

mdadm --detail told me
State: clean, degraded, recovering

```
 Active devices: 3
 Working devices: 4
 Failed devices: 0
 Spare device: 1
    
 Rebuild status: 0%
```

I heard an occasional beep, and after a while ubuntu warned me a disk is about to fail.

Search error rate is marked as FAIL. Yesterday the value was 16, but during the evening it lowered. Now it is 0.

```
Value 0
Normalized 1
Threshold 50
Worst 1
```

Also it says that the latest self test failed. I have tried to do both a short and a long self test but both fails. I booted Ubuntu live and tried but both self tests failed. Disk benchmark gives a curve similar to the another Toshiba drive. (Read speed declining).

Right now mdadm --detail outputs the same result, except rebuild status is now 17%

The seek error rate being back to 0 has me hoping it was an anomaly and I don't need to wait for a slow warranty service again. But since the self tests fails... What do you more knowledgeable say?

Comment: "So I bought 4 new Toshiba Nas drives."
How did you do that?

Comment: With money. Or what are you getting at? Anyhow I decided to play it safe at mailed customer support wor warranty, their sluggish support are yet to respond.

Comment: 2 out of your 4 simultaneously discs failed giving reason to assume that there may be a common cause. Did you buy them online causing them to be sent in a parcel with improper packaging or did you buy them in a shop? Next thing to examine is the label. Did you get refurbished ones?

Comment: Ordered from a reputable online shop, but the packaging and box seemed adequate and undamaged at the time. How do I identify refurbished ones?

Comment: Check the serial number in the support area of your drive manufacturer. Check the drive label for prints like "refurbished" or "recertified".

Comment: Did you find out what caused the drop of the seek error rate?